# Remove duplicated rows with same Timestamp but different values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have "duplicated" rows in Bigquery and I need to keep just the last occurrence grouped by id of element.

As you can see, these are not duplicated rows, those are duplicated Timestamps with different values. I need to keep one registry per Timestamp.

I run this query to get the example:

```
select 
    oid_asset_element, 
    TimeStamp_600s, 
    AmplifierTemperature_S0 , 
    AmplifierTemperature_S1  
from 
    `XXX.YYY.ZZZ` 
where TimeStamp_600s = '2020-03-29T03:50:00' 
  and oid_asset_element in (5483, 5490) 
order by oid_asset_element;
```

Table with data example:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: How do you define "last occurrence" which column does the selection of the one element you want to keep. What's the logic?

Comment: @Pentium10 you can see the image, the last ocurrence of the row is the one we have to keep. The other 3 rows must be deleted.

I added to description the query I used to search for the values.

Comment: @PepeElias don't go backwards with question edits...

Comment: It's confusing. How do you define "last occurrence" visually it may be last in the image, but in script you need to define that with an "order by" and a field. I think you are missing a field for "last occurrence".

Comment: @Pentium10 thats the point. I cannot order the table by any field, I have to use "the last added value is the valid ones" but I heard about Bigquery coalesce tables and will not return always the same order (at this moment, the order is the same, we will require just the last occurrence).

Comment: without a field and processing this is a random job, it will choose whatever value will find, not the last one as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample data, the timestamps all look the same.  Assuming they are really different, you can use `qualify`:

```
select t.*
from `table` t
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by oid_asset_element order by timestamp_600s desc) = 1;
```

If you want to actually delete rows (and I would instead suggest putting the data into a new table), you could do:

```
delete from `table` t
    where timestamp_600s < (select max(t2.timestamp_600s)
                            from `table` t2
                            where t2.oid_asset_element = t.oid_asset_element
                           );
```

Comment: This is perfect with qualify but I have more Timestamps in the table (2 year of data) so how can I do the same but with diferent Timestamps?

5477 2020-01-01T00:00:00 1.0 0
5477 2020-01-01T00:00:00 1.0 25
5477 2020-01-01T00:00:10 1.0 0
5477 2020-01-01T00:00:10 1.0 24
5477 2020-01-01T00:00:20 1.0 0
5477 2020-01-01T00:00:20 1.0 23

Comment: @PepeElias . . . A new question should be asked as a *question*, not a comment.